# Django CustomUser with OneToOne realtion has no USERNAME_FIELD when creating a new one

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So I have a CustomUserModel and I'm using that to create my extended models
models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Role(models.TextChoices):
        ADMIN = 'ADMIN', 'Admin',
        COMPANY = 'COMPANY', 'Company',
        STUDENT = 'STUDENT', 'Student'

    base_role = Role.ADMIN

    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Role.choices)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.role = self.base_role
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class UserCompanyManager(BaseUserManager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        results = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return results.filter(role=User.Role.COMPANY)


class UserCompany(User):
    base_role = User.Role.COMPANY

    company = UserCompanyManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

My form looks like this

```
class CompanySignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    company_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password confirmation", widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )

    class Meta:
        model = UserCompany
        fields = ['email', 'company_name']

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = True
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        print('User created! ', user)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        company = Company.objects.create(
            user=user,
            company_name=self.cleaned_data.get('company_name')
        )
        print("Company created! ", company)
        return company
```

And my admin.py looks like this

```
class CompanyAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ordering = ('company_name',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_display = ('company_name', 'user')
    list_filter = ()
    search_fields = ('company_name', 'user')
    fieldsets = ((None, {'fields': ('company_name', 'user')}),)
    add_form = CompanyAdminSignUpForm
admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

When I click on **add company** on admin site I'm getting this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFqfS.png)
Should I somehow change my models or form? I want to do the same for Student but that will do the same thing

When I use that form somewhere else it looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQjWV.png)
and I can create new Company (also creates new User with Company role) with this

Comment: In your CompanyAdmin class, you refer to CompanyADMINSignUpForm.  The problem is likely there - can you provide that too?

Comment: @SamSparx Oh, it's a typo that I've made by copying different state of code as I was trying multiple ways. But I have my **CompanySignUpForm** there

Comment: I wonder if this is because you are registering it as register(Company, CompanyAdmin), when you are really creating a UserCompany object.